# How to unit test AppInsights exception handler of a ASP WebAPI service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to add a global exception handler in a WebAPI service.

The code something like [this](https://github.com/AppInsightsSamples/WebApi_2.x_UnhandledExceptions/blob/master/WebApi2WithMVC/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs#L23), on the line 23.

Is there a way to write a unit test for that handler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is, but you need to know what you're looking for. 
I am assuming that by implementing your own IExceptionHandler, you want specific things to happen when exceptions are thrown. For example, you may want an ILogger to call a LogException() method as such:

```
class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public void RunAction(Action unsafeAction)
    {
       try{
       unsafeAction.Invoke();
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
         _logger.LogException(ex)
       }
    }
}
```

To unit-test this, you could write something to the likes of:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RunAction_WhenActionThrowsException_LoggerIsInvoked()
{
    // Arrange
    var badException = new Exception("I'm bad");
    var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();
    var instance = new ExceptionHandler(loggerMock.Object);
    var badMethod = () => throw badException;

    // Act
    instance.RunAction(badMethod);

    // Assert
    loggerMock.Verify(logger => logger.LogException(badException), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's a good example. but what I want to test is whether exception handler I registered works well when the controllers throw exceptions. It's something like a integrate test. I wonder if the unit test framework could support that.

Comment: You don't need to. An Exception is an exception no matter what. And the Exception handler will work on controllers if it works in this unit test. Code cannot behave differently when it is as explicit as here. 

For integration tests, you should look at frameworks like SpecFlow to do BDD with. http://www.specflow.org/

Comment: By the way; In your controller, you only need to test that the ExceptionHandler is doing the wrapping around your unsafe methods, nothing more, since the ExceptionHandler itself is already tested.